# Trying to populate an array in javascript,

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to populate an array of data from HTML Inputs using the push method in JavaScript, but when I print in the console the array variables I can see that instead of pushing the values from the HTML inputs to the next index in the array,
it's just creating a new array instead. as you can see in the screenshot

```js
function addData() {

  // save the values from the inputs
  // display the calculation and the values on the screen and save it as a local storage
  let strategyValue, sharesValue, enterPriceValue, stopLossValue, profitPriceValue, stockNameValue;
  let soldArray = [];
  let boughtArray = [];


  // creating html nodes
  let breakLine = document.createElement("br");
  let stockStrategy = document.createElement("h2");
  let stockValue = document.createElement("h2");
  let stockPrice = document.createElement("h2");
  let stockStopLoss = document.createElement("h2");
  let stockProfitPrice = document.createElement("h2");
  let stockName = document.createElement("h2");

  // saveing the values into variblies
  strategyValue = document.getElementById('strategy').value; // strategy type
  sharesValue = document.getElementById('inputShares').value; // number of shares 
  enterPriceValue = document.getElementById('enterPrice').value; // bought share price
  stopLossValue = document.getElementById('stopLoss').value; // stop loss price
  profitPriceValue = document.getElementById('profitPrice').value; // sold price
  stockNameValue = document.getElementById('stockName').value; // stock name 

  // append value to the html node 
  stockStrategy.innerHTML = strategyValue;
  stockValue.innerHTML = sharesValue;
  stockPrice.innerHTML = enterPriceValue;
  stockStopLoss.innerHTML = stopLossValue;
  stockProfitPrice.innerHTML = profitPriceValue;
  stockName.innerHTML = stockNameValue;

  // i want to add the stockTitle append it to the div-result in the html node

  divResult = document.getElementById('divResult');

  let div = document.createElement("div");

  div.className = 'div-result'

  div.appendChild(stockName);
  div.appendChild(stockStrategy);
  div.appendChild(stockPrice);
  div.appendChild(stockStopLoss);
  div.appendChild(stockProfitPrice);
  div.appendChild(stockValue);
  div.appendChild(breakLine);

  divResult.append(div)

  // i want to push the value of the sold price into the sold array
  // also push the value of the bought price into the bought  array  

  soldArray.push(profitPriceValue);
  boughtArray.push(enterPriceValue);

  console.log(soldArray);
  console.log(boughtArray);
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <h1>Power Tracker</h1>
</div>
<div class="div-main-inputs">
  <div class="div-inputs">
    <label>Stock Name</label>
    <input value="" type="text" class="input-stock" id='stockName'>
    <label>Choice Strategy</label>
    <input value="" type="text" class="input-strategy" id='strategy'>
  </div>
  <div class="div-secondInputs">
    <label>Bought Price</label>
    <input value="" type="number" class="input-enter" id='enterPrice'>
    <label>Stop Loss Price</label>
    <input value="" type="number" class="input-stop-loss" id='stopLoss'>
    <label>Profit Price</label>
    <input value="" type="number" class="input-profit-price" id='profitPrice'>
    <label>Choice Shares</label>
    <input value="" type="number" class="input-shares" id='inputShares'>
  </div>
  <button class="btn-submit" onclick="addData()">Submit</button>
</div>
<div class="div-result0" id='divResult'>
</div>
```

[image: Here is a screenshot of the console]

Comment: Well you define the two arrays each time inside of addData. Sounds like you want to keep values so it would have to be defined outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the arrays outside of the function.

At the moment new arrays are created every time the function is running.

Like this:

```
let soldArray = [];
let boughtArray = [];


function addData() {

  // save the values from the inputs
  // display the calculation and the values on the screen and save it as a local storage
  let strategyValue, sharesValue, enterPriceValue, stopLossValue, profitPriceValue, stockNameValue;
 


  // creating html nodes
  let breakLine = document.createElement("br");
  let stockStrategy = document.createElement("h2");
  let stockValue = document.createElement("h2");
  let stockPrice = document.createElement("h2");
  let stockStopLoss = document.createElement("h2");
  let stockProfitPrice = document.createElement("h2");
  let stockName = document.createElement("h2");

  // saveing the values into variblies
  strategyValue = document.getElementById('strategy').value; // strategy type
  sharesValue = document.getElementById('inputShares').value; // number of shares 
  enterPriceValue = document.getElementById('enterPrice').value; // bought share price
  stopLossValue = document.getElementById('stopLoss').value; // stop loss price
  profitPriceValue = document.getElementById('profitPrice').value; // sold price
  stockNameValue = document.getElementById('stockName').value; // stock name 

  // append value to the html node 
  stockStrategy.innerHTML = strategyValue;
  stockValue.innerHTML = sharesValue;
  stockPrice.innerHTML = enterPriceValue;
  stockStopLoss.innerHTML = stopLossValue;
  stockProfitPrice.innerHTML = profitPriceValue;
  stockName.innerHTML = stockNameValue;

  // i want to add the stockTitle append it to the div-result in the html node

  divResult = document.getElementById('divResult');

  let div = document.createElement("div");

  div.className = 'div-result'

  div.appendChild(stockName);
  div.appendChild(stockStrategy);
  div.appendChild(stockPrice);
  div.appendChild(stockStopLoss);
  div.appendChild(stockProfitPrice);
  div.appendChild(stockValue);
  div.appendChild(breakLine);

  divResult.append(div)

  // i want to push the value of the sold price into the sold array
  // also push the value of the bought price into the bought  array  

  soldArray.push(profitPriceValue);
  boughtArray.push(enterPriceValue);

  console.log(soldArray);
  console.log(boughtArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems every time you run the addData function, you're initializing two empty arrays, which would be why you're seeing a new array with only 1 value each log.

You'd need to move your two array variables outside of the function.

```
let soldArray = [];
let boughtArray = [];

function addData() {
   // ...code here

   soldArray.push(profitPriceValue);
   boughtArray.push(enterPriceValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`let soldArray = [];` and `let boughtArray = [];` have functional scope because they are defined in `addData()` function . Thus every time the `addData()` is called `soldArray` and `broughtArray` are created.

The `soldArray` and `broughtArray` should be created outside the function `addData()`. To know more about scopes in [javascript](https://www.javatpoint.com/javascript-scope) .